# Wrap php string in tag

Tags: php, replace, extract

I have this string extracted from my database

```
[###TITLE###] 
 Passed in 12%. 
[###TITLE###] 
1 to 2% dearer. Maintained throughout the day. 
[###TITLE###] 
 18.5m finer 2 to 3% dearer. 19.0m coarser 1 to 2% dearer. 
[###TITLE###] 
 19.5m finer 1 to 2% dearer. 20.0m coarser firm.
```

My question is:
How can I wrap just the text between ###] and [###
( I want to wrap in a div the text without [### TITLE ###]

P.S: The whole text is just a string.

Expected Output

```
[###TITLE###] 
 Passed in 12%. 
[###TITLE###] 
 <div class="text">1 to 2% dearer. Maintained throughout the day.</div>
[###TITLE###] 
 <div class="text">18.5m finer 2 to 3% dearer. 19.0m coarser 1 to 2% dearer.</div> 
[###TITLE###] 
 <div class="text">19.5m finer 1 to 2% dearer. 20.0m coarser firm.</div>
```

How can I extract from the database in one variable just [### TITLE ###]
and in another variable the rest of the text.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I've just edited :)

Comment: And why `Passed in ..` is not wrapped?

Comment: because `[###TITLE###] 
 Passed in 12%. 
[###TITLE###] 
1 to 2% dearer. Maintained throughout the day. 
[###TITLE###] 
 18.5m finer 2 to 3% dearer. 19.0m coarser 1 to 2% dearer. 
[###TITLE###] 
 19.5m finer 1 to 2% dearer. 20.0m coarser firm.` is a string. <br> and i don't know how to wrap only `Passed in ....`

Comment: Mmmm, because what?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression based string replacement:

```
<?php

$input = <<< EOT
[###TITLE###]
 Passed in 12%.
[###TITLE###]
1 to 2% dearer. Maintained throughout the day.
[###TITLE###]
 18.5m finer 2 to 3% dearer. 19.0m coarser 1 to 2% dearer.
[###TITLE###]
 19.5m finer 1 to 2% dearer. 20.0m coarser firm.
EOT;

$output = preg_replace(
    '/(\])\s+([^\[]*)\s+(\[)?/m', 
    "\\1\n<div class=\"text\">\\2</div>\n\\3", 
    $input
);

var_dump($output);
```

The output of this is:

```
string(323) "[###TITLE###]
<div class="text">Passed in 12%. </div>
[###TITLE###]
<div class="text">1 to 2% dearer. Maintained throughout the day. </div>
[###TITLE###]
<div class="text">18.5m finer 2 to 3% dearer. 19.0m coarser 1 to 2% dearer. </div>
[###TITLE###]
<div class="text">19.5m finer 1 to 2% dearer. 20.0m coarser firm.</div>
"
```

Note: take care that there is a trailing white space at the end of the input, otherwise the expression will deliver a slightly different output. If in doubt simply append a single blank character to the input ;-)

---

Another approach, in my eyes much more flexible, is a constructive creation of the desired output. For that you first use a regular expression based multi line capture. Then you can craft the output exactly as you like:

```
<?php

$input = <<< EOT
[###TITLE###]
 Passed in 12%.
[###TITLE###]
1 to 2% dearer. Maintained throughout the day.
[###TITLE###]
 18.5m finer 2 to 3% dearer. 19.0m coarser 1 to 2% dearer.
[###TITLE###]
 19.5m finer 1 to 2% dearer. 20.0m coarser firm.
EOT;

preg_match_all('/(\\[.+\\]\s+)([^\[]*\s*)\s/', $input, $tokens);

$output = '';
for($i=0; $i<count($tokens[0]); $i++) {
    $output .= sprintf("%s<div class=\"text\">%s</div>\n", $tokens[1][$i], $tokens[2][$i]);
}

var_dump($output);
```

The output here is again:

```
string(330) "[###TITLE###]
 <div class="text">Passed in 12%. </div>
[###TITLE###]
<div class="text">1 to 2% dearer. Maintained throughout the day. </div>
[###TITLE###]
 <div class="text">18.5m finer 2 to 3% dearer. 19.0m coarser 1 to 2% dearer. </div>
[###TITLE###]
 <div class="text">19.5m finer 1 to 2% dearer. 20.0m coarser firm.</div>
"
```

---

Warning: in both cases to have to make sure that the actual title and content lines to *not* contain square brackets apart from those actually delimiting the title. Handling such cases *is* possible, but makes things much more complex.